# jquery not response in wordpress post

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

im using the latest wordpress 4.9.5 which loaded jquery automatically as i seen in page source.
but when i tried to put this code on wordpress post to check nothing happened.

```
<script type="text/javascript>
window.onload = function() {
  if (window.jQuery) {  
    // jQuery is loaded  
    alert("Yeah!");
  } else {
    // jQuery is not loaded
    alert("Doesn't Work");
  }
}
</script>
```

it was working last night, but today it isn't anymore without any changes.

cheers

Comment: Do you receive any error in console?

Comment: Are you trying to embed javascript _in_ a WordPress posting? The community is going to need a better-written explanation of your issue to help.

Comment: ah there is an error in console ...i have fixed that and its working now..thank you @31piy

Answer (score 0):

there was an extra "}" and ")" and wordpress also added some p tags. need to delete those and now its working again. got to see the source and console to make sure the code is correctly written.

```
 <script>
window.onload = function() {
if (window.jQuery) {  
    // jQuery is loaded  
    alert("Yeah!");
} else {
    // jQuery is not loaded
    alert("Doesn't Work");
}};</script>
```